# Convert MPEG4 to H264

Tags: video, h.264, codec, mpeg-4, video-codecs

Does anyone have any ideas on how to convert a mp4 file(mp4/aac) with MPEG4 codec to H264 codec. I can't using ffmpeg on command line since this needs to be done on server. I muxed audio and video and created a movie with the MPEG4 codec, but when I change to H264 codec, I'm facing problems...

I tried using https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/mp4parser/examples/mux/filebased/MuxMe.java to mux my video and audio, but it gives me an IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: if it has to be done on the server there are wrappers for most languages that allow you to use ffmpeg. how are you converting the file?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to clarify? I ask because MPEG-4 is a container format, used to multiplex video, audio, and other tracks.  H.264 (aka AVC) is a very popular video codec used in MPEG-4. Do you want to debox your H.264 data, removing it from its MPEG-4 wrapper? Or what?

Comment: @O.Jones I understand that .mp4 is a container, but my video is a MPEG4 codec, but it won't display on the browsers, until I change it to H264 codec. I can't se ffmpeg on command line since this has to be done on the server..

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Hey, I looked into https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser , to try to convert my existing MPEG4 video and add audio to it, using MuxMe.java (https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/org/mp4parser/examples/mux/filebased/MuxMe.java) , but I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException..